# Change IOS Application Name with windows C# third party program

Tags: c#, ios

I have an IPhone application that change its resources in C# application and change its UI with changing images and styles.
Now i want to change application name that appear blow icon when installed in IOS phone with my C# program.
I know that i should extract .ipa package as zip file and open info.plist and change search my previous or old app name and replace with new string and then repack again. but because it's format is binary when new string length is different with previous one , when i install .ipa in IOS phone show me an error message that ipa file is invalid.
what tool maybe exist that can i use with my C# code to rename it without problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should extract the ipa package. then find info.plist file in extracted file and then open file. then search your previous application name in file and replace it with new name.
consider your new name characters count should equal to old name character count. good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a problem that you rename the app in the plist. You just need to sign the ipa again with your developer certificate after renaming.

The easiest way is to use xcode's command tools, but unfortunately you need mac os x. You can look at https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign , which is a great/easy tool built on top of xcode command tools.

Maybe you can find a windows tool that allows you to sign an ipa file. I haven't looked into such a tool... so it's just a maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plconvert.exe from apple corporation to edit info.plist:
`plconvert.exe <inBinaryFileName> <outXmlFileName>`
`plconvert.exe <inXMLFilName> <outBinaryFileName> -binary`